# Canvas pointer lock

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to lock my mouse to a canvas element. 
The canvas element exists and pointer lock is available.

Here is my console output:

- Pointer lock exists
- not locked
- There was an error

Already checked these two links, but couldn't find my mistake. Since full screen is not longer required to achieve pointerlock, I didn't initiate full screen.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Pointer_Lock

Of course I also have an exit function for the pointlocker. But I guess the problem shoulnd't be there.

```
var check_pointerLock = 'pointerLockElement' in document ||
'mozPointerLockElement' in document ||
'webkitPointerLockElement' in document;

if(check_pointerLock){
    console.log("Pointer lock exists");
    //canvas element to lock pointer to
    canvas.requestPointerLock = canvas.requestPointerLock ||
         canvas.mozRequestPointerLock ||
         canvas.webkitRequestPointerLock;
    canvas.requestPointerLock();

    //check for errors
    document.addEventListener('pointerlockerror', errorCallback, false);
    document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockerror', errorCallback, false);
    document.addEventListener('webkitpointerlockerror', errorCallback, false);



    // 1) Used as a boolean check: are we pointer locked?
    if (!!document.pointerLockElement) {
      console.log("locked");
    } else {
      // pointer is not locked
      console.log("not locked");
    }


}
function errorCallback() {
    console.log("There was an error");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used a key to initiate the pointer lock, what is unfortunately not possible. Therefore I had to stick to a mouseclick event.